# DataSet To Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I do not have Excel installed on my server, it is installed on the PC that will be exporting.  I am wanting to export the dataset to Excel, but am unsure of how to do such as we have Excel XP, Excel 2000, Excel 2007 and Excel 2013 being used.  How can I export w/o targeting a specific Excel version so that it works on all computers?

Comment: you can use CSV file it works in all excel version

Comment: Just use a library such as EPPlus, NPOI, or Open XML SDK to generate a .xlsx file. See [How to open new file formats in earlier versions of Microsoft Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/924074).

Comment: @mason can you provide syntax?

Comment: @user2676140 No that's too broad of a request. You are perfectly capable of looking at the examples those tools provide.

Comment: Using this option would I Be able to set row height?

Comment: I listed three options. You can explore the options to find out their capabilities yourself. They're all free and readily available.

Answer (score 2):

The most portable format is .csv which will work on all platforms but will only work for simple data.

If you have more than simple data you can just export to the oldest version of excel you want to support, the newer ones will then upgrade the file.